# Sending emails from websites on shared hosting - what solutions do I have

Tags: email, smtp, email-spam

I spent weeks on researching the net on wich solution should I use in order to correctly send emails from my websites hosted on shared hosting accounts, but the more I read - the more confused I get.

So this is my situation!

I have among others, an ecommerce website built on OpenCart, on a shared hosting account and a few email addresses in cPanel, like sales@mydomain.com, newsletter@mydomain.com, contact@mydomain.com, etc. These email accounts are also accessible via roundCube by the user at email.mydomain.com and via IMAP\SMTP on their email clients like Thunderbird.

The website has these email addresses set up and it uses (at leas Opencart does) php mail() to send emails for events (new order, contact, quote, etc).

Since last year or so, providers like Yahoo keeps banning the server's IP address and emails get bounced back with failure messages, Gmail recipients get them in Spam folder, etc. I almost monthly ask my hosting provider to change IP address, ask Yahoo or spam services to unblock the IP address, do tests, etc and I don't even have a large number of emails going, like 100 per month, most of them are Ask for a quote wich are plain text messages.
In other words, it isn't working.
What I am looking for what solution should I use to send emails from websites hosted on shared accounts, that is transactional emails and newsletter emails without upsetting Yahoo,Google,etc. subdomains? external smtp service? configure email accounts in a specific way? What do you guys use ?

Comment: ditch your provider, they're probably a spam haven, and yahoo/google/et all are blocking entire netblocks, and you're getting caught in the crossfire.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to add extensions to Opencart on your shared host, you may want to consider adding the phpmailer extension (http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3932).  This will enable you to send all outgoing mail from Opencart via phpmailer, which can be setup to send mail through a remote SMTP relay (such as smtp.gmail.com, sendgrid, or some other remote SMTP relay).  A reputable remote SMTP relay will probably be less likely to be blacklisted than your host's SMTP relay that the php mail() command is currently using.

Comment: Ok so I can go and use a 3rd party SMTP relay to send transactional emails in my websites but what about sending emails "manually" when website owners reply to customers? Can I set their accounts to use the same 3rd party SMTP with the custom address of contact@mydomain.com like Google Apps does ?